# Rails 4 - pundit - how to write if statement to check user permissions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, permissions, pundit

I'm trying to learn how to use pundit with my Rails 4 app.

I have a potential use policy. The potential use table has an attribute called :user_id.

I want users to be permitted to update instances if they created them. I'm trying to figure out how to get the update action to work.

My current attempts are shown below.

```
class PotentialUsePolicy < ApplicationPolicy

    attr_reader :user, :record

  def initialize(user, record)
    @user = user
    @record = record
  end


    def index?
        true if user.is_admin?
    end

    def show?
        true

    end

    def new?
      true
  end

    def create?
        new?
    end

    def update?
        if @user.id == @potential_use.user_id

        # if user.id == potential_use.user_id
            true
        else
            false
        end
    end

    def destroy?
        update?
    end

    def edit?
                true
    end

    def potential_use
        record
    end 

end
```

When I try these, I keep getting errors saying:

```
undefined method `user_id' for nil:NilClass
```

I don't understand why I get this message. When I look in the console, I can see an entry which has a user id.

```
p = PotentialUse.where(project_id: 26)
  PotentialUse Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "potential_uses".* FROM "potential_uses" WHERE "potential_uses"."project_id" = $1  [["project_id", 26]]
 => #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<PotentialUse id: 9, comment: "adsfsfdadfasdddxxddbbdd", project_id: 26, created_at: "2016-08-18 23:16:06", updated_at: "2016-08-24 01:06:00", user_id: 1, private_comment: false>]> 
2.3.0p0 :016 >
```

When I look in the view (without trying to use the pundit policy, the page renders with all the right content, including the user name (which is accessed by the user_id).

The update action in my potential use controller has:

```
def update
    authorize @potential_use
    respond_to do |format|
      if @potential_use.update(potential_use_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @project, notice: 'Potential use was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @potential_use }
      else
        format.html { render @project }
        format.json { render json: @potential_use.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

Can anyone see what I've done wrong?

Answer (score 3):

To check if a user has permission to perform an action on a policy from a view:

```
<% if policy(@post).update? %>
  <%= link_to "Edit post", edit_post_path(@post) %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your error is because you call `@potential_use.user_id` but `@potential_use` is never declared in the policy class. You defined `potential_use` as a method, but in that method you call `record`, instead of `@record`.

So, to fix it you should call `potential_use` instead of `@potential_use` and change the method to:

```
def potential_use
    @record
end
```

Or simply, call `@record.user_id` instead of `@potential_use.user_id`.

Besides, as you can see in the [Pundit readme](https://github.com/varvet/pundit#policies), when you inherit from `ApplicationPolicy`, you don't need to declare:

```
attr_reader :user, :record

def initialize(user, record)
  @user = user
  @record = record
end
```

As it is already in the parent class.

Answer (score -1):

You access the authorized objects with your accessors. In your example you probaly called

```
authorize @potential_use
```

in your controller update action. The update? method on your controller would look like this:

```
def update?
    user.id == record.user_id
end
```

Comment: But if have a method called potential use in my policy which is defined as record. So -- I think my attempt (commented version) is the same as yours. it doesnt work (nether does the version where I try using '@' symbol.

Comment: Also, I tried your suggestion, but it gives this error: undefined method `user_id' for #<Class:0x007fba181c5f00>

Comment: Iam sorry if this question is inappropriate, but did you assign the @potential_use variable? Maybe in a before_action or something?